# jquery bootstrap datepicker only month and day

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

i have example

http://jsfiddle.net/rAdV6/20/?

in jqueryui datepicker

third demo example

where is only month and date.

i want this on bootstrap datepicker.

```
<http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/>?
```

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround that I have made for this is to remove the year from the date title before the datepicker show. Below is the code I used to initialize the datepicker:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    format : 'MM dd',
}).on('show', function() {
    // remove the year from the date title before the datepicker show
    var dateText  = $(".datepicker-days .datepicker-switch").text();
    var dateTitle = dateText.substr(0, dateText.length - 5);
    $(".datepicker-days .datepicker-switch").text(dateTitle);
});
```

Comment: This is a good idea and nearly worked for me but I found that the date text is not always updated on show. So you can get 'September' displayed the first time, then 'Sept' and then nothing. So I changed the above code to replace numbers with nothing like this:
var dateTitle = dateText.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');

Comment: You may also want to hide the days of the week since these are depdendant on the year. I did this with: $(".dow").hide();

Comment: issue with this is that there's inconsistency if the user loops around to new years. i.e. some years will have 2/29

Answer (score 2):

This is what works for me. Using jQuery split function.

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    format : 'MM dd',
}).on('show', function() {
    // remove the year from the date title before the datepicker show
        var dateText  = $(".datepicker-days .datepicker-switch").text().split(" ");
        var dateTitle = dateText[0];
        $(".datepicker-days .datepicker-switch").text(dateTitle);
        $(".datepicker-months .datepicker-switch").css({"visibility":"hidden"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Jquery datepicker you can do something like this :

```
$(".daypicker").datepicker( { 
    changeYear: false, 
    dateFormat: 'MM-dd',
}).focus(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-year").hide();
});
```

It wont affect to other datepickers in same page.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap datepicker module is a third party tool which you need to download, install and reference from your code.

Download the javascript library from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/.

All you need to do is add the following line of code and then it works.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "mm/dd"
})`
```

Comment: i want only month and day, not year, this is my problem.

Comment: Try this out: http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=mm%2Fdd&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
format: "dd/mm",
weekStart: 1,
startView: 1,
maxViewMode: 1,
autoclose: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know

```
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        format : 'mm-dd',
    }).on('show', function() {

        var dateText  = $(".datepicker-days .datepicker-switch").text();
        var dateTitle = dateText.substr(0, dateText.length - 5);
        $(".datepicker-days .datepicker-switch").text(dateTitle);

        var months= ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

        if(dateTitle=='' && $("#notify_month").val()!=""){
           var month_val =  parseInt($("#notify_month").val());
           dateTitle = months[month_val-1];
           $(".datepicker-days .datepicker-switch").text(dateTitle);
        }

        $(".datepicker-months .datepicker-switch").css({"visibility":"hidden"});
    });
```