# How to extract Month from the Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to bootstrap datepicker. All i need do is, when i click the `id="filter"` button, the text of the `id="btn-date-range"` is to be changed like **June-20 to June-29**. When i run my code i was able to change the text of the `id="btn-date-range"` button like **2020-06-20 to 2020-06-29**. How do i extract the Month name and add it to the text of `id="btn-date-range"`?
Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
 <a class="btn btn-info btn-outline btn-rounded my-2" id="btn-date-range"><b>Last 7 Days</b></a>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="control-label"> From </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control date" name="upper_element_start_date" id="upper_element_start_date">
            </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="control-label"> To </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control date" name="upper_element_end_date" id="upper_element_end_date">
            </div>                      
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="filterUpperDashboardDetails();" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="filter"><i class="fas fa-filter"></i> Filter </button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var startDate = '';
var endDate   = '';

$('.date').datepicker(
{
     format             : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
     todayBtn           : "linked",
     keyboardNavigation : false,
     forceParse         : false,
     calendarWeeks      : true,
     autoclose          : true,
     todayHighlight     : true,
});

function filterUpperDashboardDetails(){
        startDate = $('#upper_element_start_date').val();
        endDate = $('#upper_element_end_date').val();
        $('#btn-date-range').text('From ' + startDate + ' To ' + endDate);
        $('#btn-date-range').addClass('font-bold');
}
```

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824696/jquery-bootstrap-datepicker-only-month-and-day

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Actually sir I just want the ````yyyy-mm-dd format```` in my datepicker value. In the same time i just want to extract the Month and date from the selected value as i mentioned earlier