# How to get day from date bootstrap date picker in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a bootstrap date picker and I have selected the date from input fields but I need to retrieve the day from the date please help me how can I get the day? thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns0wA.png)

**jquery script**

```
 $('.datepicker').on('change', function (date) {
      var checkInnDate = $("#check_inn").val();
      console.log(checkInnDate);
     
  });
```

Comment: Please check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824696/jquery-bootstrap-datepicker-only-month-and-day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the split() method divides a String into char array.

```
const str = '2021-10-15';

const words = str.split('-');
console.log(words[2]);
```